# PHP echo array with an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I create an array which works fine:

```
$user_list_args = array(
 'role__in' => array('editor', 'author', 'administrator' ),
);
$user_list = get_users($user_list_args);
$user_list_array = array();
foreach ( $user_list as $user ) {
 $user_list_array[] = $user->user_nicename;
}
```

I then want to display that in an another array which is set up as follows:

```
array(
 'id' => 'task-users',
 'label' => 'User(s)',
 'type' => 'select',
 'options' => array(
  'tom',
  'jerry',
 ),
),
```

I want to change the options to be dynamic from my array as so:

```
private $fields = array(
 array(
  'id' => 'task-users',
  'label' => 'User(s)',
  'type' => 'select',
  'options' => array($user_list_array),
 ),
);
```

This generates an error:

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations

Can someone point me in the right direction? I am using PHP7 if that helps but should be usable on older versions too.

Thanks

Comment: i think you mean you want to join the arrays? not echo?

Comment: I guess? so array_join is what I need to look at?

Comment: Why are you creating the `$user_list_array` like that? If you want that array to contain the user's nice names, you only need to do `$user_list_array[] = $user->user_nicename;`

Comment: `$newArray[] = print_r($oldArray,true);` does this do what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare class properties using variables. If you need to assign values like that to the property use a constructor method and do it there.  Maybe something like this:

```
private $fields;

public function __construct() {
    // your code to define $user_list_array somewhere here
    // or passed to constructor when you instantiate the class

    $this->fields = array(
        array(
            'id' => 'task-users',
            'label' => 'User(s)',
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => array($user_list_array),
        )
    );
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php:

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

your joining not echoing and this is completely valid:

```
<?php

$user_list_array=array(
  'tom',
  'jerry',
 );

$f= array(
 'id' => 'task-users',
 'label' => 'User(s)',
 'type' => 'select',
 'options' => array($user_list_array),
);

print_r($f);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => task-users
    [label] => User(s)
    [type] => select
    [options] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => tom
                    [1] => jerry
                )

        )

)
```

OR:

```
<?php

$user_list_array=array(
  'tom',
  'jerry',
 );

$f= array(
 'id' => 'task-users',
 'label' => 'User(s)',
 'type' => 'select',
 'options' => $user_list_array,
);

print_r($f);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => task-users
    [label] => User(s)
    [type] => select
    [options] => Array
        (
            [0] => tom
            [1] => jerry
        )

)
```

Comment: I must be missing something but can't get it too work, tried every option possible, still getting the php error.....

Comment: @GarethGillman you need to provide the exact code, or at least enough for us to replicate the error